# Claymore miner not work with screen or tmux

Tags: command-line, server, bash, tmux, ethereum

I have 10 GPU attached to one system and want to mine with all, as ubuntu GUI not allow to run 10 GPU at a time, So will go with the command line and able to mine there.

Now I want to run my miner on system startup for particular this I am following [this](http://www.cryptobadger.com/2017/04/build-ethereum-mining-rig-linux/) tutorial (step-7). I have done all the things as per tutorial but not able to start ./start_only_eth.bash command(no screen session created) in screen session.

If I am executing below command, I am able to find this session using "screen -ls" command.

```
screen -dmS ethm
```

Below is my script (demo.sh)

// update

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT_DELAY=0
if [ "x$1" = "x" -o "x$1" = "xnone" ]; then
   DELAY=$DEFAULT_DELAY
else
   DELAY=$1
fi
sleep $DELAY
su aman -c "screen -dmS ethm /home/aman/Desktop/claymore/start_only_eth.bash"
```

I have added this script's path in rc.local file as mentioned in [this](http://www.cryptobadger.com/2017/04/build-ethereum-mining-rig-linux/) tutorial (step-7).

below is my rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution 
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

 sh '/home/aman/Desktop/demo.sh'
  exit 0
```

After restart if I execute "screen -ls" command I got below message

```
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-aman.
```

Note: I think problem is not in rc.local, problem is in demo.sh. If try to execute demo.sh manually the script will fail and got above message.

//
//
-------------------------- With TMUX --------------------
//
//

I have also tried this with tmux, this time I am able to run miner(manually) in tmux session but again fail to run script using rc.local for this below is my demo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -n MINER
tmux send-keys -t MINER "cd /home/aman/Desktop/claymore" C-m
tmux send-keys -t MINER "./start_only_eth.bash" C-m
```

Below is what I am getting(console) when try to test rc.local

```
aman@aman-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
[sudo] password for aman: 
[ ok ] Starting rc.local (via systemctl): rc.local.service.
```

Comment: What error message do you get when you run your script?

Comment: I am getting "No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-aman." when executing screen -ls

Comment: But what do you get when you start your script `demo.sh` in a terminal?

Comment: 1.) If I run demo.sh (tmux) manually, mining will start but same script will not work with rc.local. 2) If I run demo.sh (screen) manually nothing will happen and also not work in rc.local.     I am not getting any error in script. (They are just not working in rc.local - on system startup)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/Desktop/claymore
su aman -c "screen -dmS ethm ./start_only_eth.bash"
```

There's multiple problems with this. First of all, the path is likely to be `/home/username/Desktop/claymore`. Second, the `cd` affects the current script, and is likely not carried over to screen, across the su.

Try:

```
su aman -c "screen -dmS ethm /home/username/Desktop/claymore/start_only_eth.bash"
```

If the script `start_only_eth.bash` requires to have PWD set to that directory, place a line with

```
cd /home/username/Desktop/claymore
```

as the second line of the script.

Replace `username` with the actual username.

Comment: I have tried this but no luck for this I have update my question please check.